# Splitting the output of MySQL Group_Concat()

Tags: mysql

How do I split Group_Concat() result into different columns? I don't want to show it in the same cell separated by comma.

Comment: Doing what you suggest literally, naming exploding a comma-separated string, is a bunch of work in MySQL.  Really what you are looking for is a pivot query, where you create columns to hold the CSV content.  Can you show us a sample table so we have a better idea of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) twice after wrapping it in a `subquery`, in case you know the delimiter.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 3), '.', -1)
    FROM (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS SomeColumn
            FROM ...
    ) AS SomeTable
```

1. The first `SUBSTRING_INDEX` gets the string from **first -> n**
2. The second `SUBSTRING_INDEX` removes the string from **first -> n - 1**

Check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c927/5) example

In your case, if you know the **number of columns**, your query would look something like (assuming you have 5 strings separated by comma):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 1), '.', -1)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 2), '.', -1)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 3), '.', -1)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 4), '.', -1)
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeColumn, '.', 5), '.', -1)
    FROM (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(...) AS SomeColumn
            FROM ...
    ) AS SomeTable
```